# Is there a way to enable double buffering for SWT components?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

In the Eclipse RCP application I'm building, I noticed that when I rebuild parts of the GUI (by adding/removing controls), the GUI gets updated and redrawn immediately upon each modification, which causes a flicker effect.

Is there a way to enable double buffering, so that the GUI refresh will happen only once at the end of the event dispatch cycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Control#setRedraw(false);
...
modify
...
Control#setRedraw(true);
```

Comment: This solved the problem of flickering, many thanks!

It's still not double buffered, but at least the painting can be dereferred during the updates, that's worth as much as a double buffer :)